# Problem to pass the result to the caller for asynchronous httpWebRequest

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, silverlight

In Silverlight I want to be able to get the output from a Helper class like this:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        String ouput;
        Helper helper = new Helper(url);

        Helper.invoke(output);

    }
```

I can't see how to do that since in Helper Class I am obliged to do an asynchronous call:

```
    private String webserviceUrl;
    private XDocument xdoc = new XDocument();

    public Helper(String webserviceUrl)
    {
        this.webserviceUrl = webserviceUrl;
    }

    public void invoke(ref String output)
    {

        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(this.webserviceUrl);
        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(HandlerWebResponse), httpWebResponse);

        }
        catch
        {

        }

  }

    private void HandlerWebResponse(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
        using (StreamReader streamReader1 = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string resultString = streamReader1.ReadToEnd();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an event to notify that the service has been successfully consumed. In the event parameters you can pass the result of the invoked web services.

```
public event Action<string> ResponseResult;
```

You can then invoke this event in your web response handler:

```
private void HandlerWebResponse(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
    using (StreamReader streamReader1 = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        string resultString = streamReader1.ReadToEnd();
        if (ResponseResult != null)
             ResponseResult(resultString);

    }
}
```

And in your code the initiates the service call you can subscribe to this event to get notified when it has finished:

```
Helper helper = new Helper(url);
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Helper.ResponseResult += ResponseHandler;
    Helper.invoke(output);

}

public void ResponseHandler(string response)
{
    // do something with response
}
```

Comment: ok thanks, as I commented below it's such a hassle to create event in c# how can I know the type of event to create etc. :( so thanks for help :)

Comment: Events are not at all a hassle once you get used to them. If you use a lambada expression instead of a method to handle the event you code will be very minimalistic and fast to write. 'Helper.ResponseResult += (result) => this.TextBox.Text = result;'

Comment: Well it is proof is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441352/cannot-create-event-of-type-actionstring :)

Comment: Ok this one is real proof http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442175/error-on-httpwebrequest

Comment: @user310291: There's no indication that that's "proof" of anything to do with events. Until you've worked out what's causing the exception, you have no idea whether it's to do with asynchrony or not.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're basically trying to get away from the asynchronous model. While you *can* do that by effectively blocking until the event handler for the asynchronous request has fired, you really shouldn't. There are good reasons for Silverlight to only support asynchronous web operations - you should go with that decision.

It's fine to have a helper class to effectively perform a transformation on the result, but I'd suggest doing that in an asynchronous style - pass in an event handler which will be called when the request completes (either successfully or unsuccessfully). Transform the result (e.g. reading it as a string) and then call the event handler.

It can be a bit of a pain, admittedly, but you really need to start thinking in terms of an asynchronous model.

You might also want to look at `WebClient` which already has support for fetching an HTTP result as a string.

Comment: Async is great when it is justified. But in my context I need to block everything until I get it. The problem is not the async the problem is it's really a hassle in .NET to create message and handler ! They should have created a better syntax :(

Comment: @user310291: Well C# 5 will have much better async support. But do you really want your UI to freeze until you've got all the data?

Comment: Yes I want to freeze in this case user should not do anything :). By the way I have now this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441352/cannot-create-event-of-type-actionstring

Comment: @user310291: They shouldn't even be able to move the window around, or close the app? That sounds like a sucky user experience.

Comment: why would it be sucky if it lasts very short. And coping with closing a window should be taken into account by the framework: why can't I freeze just the client area ms should have made this feature available ? If I allow asynch people can click on something else and I would have to deal with managing this error context myself which is a maintenance nightmare !

Comment: And if I'm on windows phone they cannot move the window and they can leave the app by the way.

Comment: @user310291: It would have been worth mentioning that you're on WP7 to start with - you *don't* want to use WebClient in that situation, as it does too much on the UI thread. But you really *shouldn't* block the UI thread. You say it's going to just be short - but if you're on a mobile network, you may have *very* high latency. If you want to disable bits of the UI (buttons etc), just disable them. That's much more appropriate than freezing the UI thread. I wouldn't be surprised if "not blocking the UI thread while waiting for the network" was part of the certification, even...

Comment: I didn't say I limit to WP7 :). What I hate is not to have the choice to decide. Why can't they propose both synchronous and asynchronous ? It may usefull at least when you need to quickly make a functional prototype to do first sync and the later async.

Comment: Second MS is mixing technical workflow problem with functional workflow problem. My functional workflow is sequential while the technical workflow is asynchronous. The technical workflow should not dictate the functional workflow. I mean there should be a way to have at high level a sequential viewpoint even if underlying it's asynchronous otherwise it can become very difficult to maintain something that was functionally very basic.

Comment: Third it's a technical nightmare I get a security exception http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442175/error-on-httpwebrequest whereas I can do the same synchronous call in ASP.NET without any problem

Comment: When you say " If you want to disable bits of the UI (buttons etc), just disable them. " well what's difference with freezing the client area by the framework ? None except in the first case I have to handle the hassle myself :)

Comment: @user310291: No, there's a *huge* difference between letting the UI respond to events such as reorientation, repainting etc, but preventing the *specific* user interactions you want to prohibit, and blocking the UI thread. But you seemed determined to ignore best practice, so I'm not sure there's much more I can do to help you.