# cannot create event of type Action<String>

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

Following discuss [Problem to pass the result to the caller for asynchronous httpWebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441217/problem-to-pass-the-result-to-the-caller-for-asynchronous-httpwebrequest) I tried to created an event of type Action

```
public event Action<string> ResponseResult;
```

but Silverlight refuses event keyword: it says expect class, delegate, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining the event in the wrong place. If you have your Helper class (reference the original post) then you need to declare the event inside this class:

```
public class Helper
{
     public event Action<string> ResponseResult;

     // rest of code...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C# is C#, whether it's against Silverlight or the .NET Framework that you're building.

My guess is that you're trying to define an event outside of the scope of a class.